# How to login to a website programmatically from the server

Tags: java, php, ruby, login-script

Using any language (php, java, ruby, python), what's the best way to login to a website programmatically from the server? (for example, login to amazon, jetblue, etc. )

Are there are some frameworks to make this easier?

Comment: I am not trying to create a new account, just login :)

Answer (score 2):

You could use Ruby or Python with Mechanize ([ruby implementation](http://mechanize.rubyforge.org/), [python implementation](http://wwwsearch.sourceforge.net/mechanize/)).

Mechanize is basically a browser and you can have it programmatically submit forms or send the appropriate HTTP request/response data to maintain a "fake" session.

There are a number of these kinds of tools, I've recently had some good experiences using python+mechanize.

Comment: Also had good success with python + mechanize.  Also BeautifulSoup for HTML parsing along with mechanize

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, this has to be configured on a per-site basis.  Each site uses its own login forms / urls, and potentially uses a different-named cookie (or whatever) to track your login session.